# Spring Tool Suite: Error Importing Spring Getting Started Content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to import a REST project in the Spring getting started guide, however running into class def not found error in Spring Tool Suite.

In Spring Tool Suite: 
File > New > Other:  Spring > Import Spring Getting Started content

Getting Started Guide > Consuming Rest: 
Build Type: Gradle (STS): 
Code Sets: initial, complete

When I click Finish the following error pops up.
I have Gradle 2.11 installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:
1) Select Gradle (Buildship). This expects one to have Gradle eclipse plugin from Buildship installed
2) Install STS Gradle eclipse plugin and then try the wizard again after STS restarted. (Update site: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.5/ select 'Core/Eclipse Integration for Gradle' category)

Comment: To add a little background, the error shown in the question isn't supposed to happen. Instead there was supposed to be a nicer message warning that required 'Gradle STS Tooling' isn't installed. But in some version of the tools there was a bug which made this error 'escape' from where it was supposed to be caught and handled. Current release should be better and give you a less confusing error.